# How to release a update of tauri for intranet users, with entrypoints only avalible on http?

Tags: rust, tauri

I have mass users and want to use the updater to automate updating my tauri application, but the users are in an HTTP intranet while the tauri requires [the updater's entrypoints must be `HTTPS` link for productions](https://tauri.app/v1/api/config#updaterconfig). So is there a way to release my tauri update to an updater that is using http but not https?

Comment: I think it should work.. that is why you have to signed so it can compare if its valid https://tauri.app/v1/guides/distribution/updater

Comment: [the configuration document](https://tauri.app/v1/api/config/#updaterconfig) has said that "TLS is enforced on production", and my intranet users indeed is in a "production" environment.

Comment: Since I haven't found out a solution to accomplish this, I finally decide to walk around the "HTTP production" situation, by making the "HTTP" users to the "HTTPS" ones.